# form with 2 buttons need to call different functions based on value

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

I have a page which has lot of post data in the url.

For example,
www.test.com/test.php?userid='tester'&name=test&so on

The above page has a form that has something like this:

```
<? 
$set=get_value_set;
if($set ==1) {
    $set_value="SET";
} else {
    $set_value="UNSET";
}

?>
<form name="test">
<input type="text" readonly="READONLY" value="<? echo $user_id; ?>">
<input type="submit" value="Email" name="submit_user">
<input type="submit" value="<? echo $set_value; ?>" name="submit_user">

<? 
function setuser()
{
//sets the value

}
function email_user()
{
//sets the value

}
?>
```

there are two buttons above, when I click on email, i want the value of email button to be passed to the email_user function and do some proceesing there. Similar thing when I click on the set button.

**NOTE:But in both cases above, I want the form to remain in the same page with the same post data in the url, but I also want the page to be refreshed so that the set button can have a value of Set or Unset depending on the database update.**

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would start to remove the `submit` action of each button and change them to

```
<input type="button" class="btn-Email" value="Email" name="submit_user" />
<input type="button" class="btn-Other" value="<? echo $set_value; ?>" name="submit_user" />
```

and then, using jQuery, you can easily process each click and submit the form

```
$(function() {

  $(".btn-Email").click(function() {
    // append anything you want
    var but_email_value = $(this).val(), // or $(".btn-Email").val()
        btn_other_value = $(".btn-Other").val();

    $("form").submit();
  });

  $(".btn-Other").click(function() {
    // append anything you want
    var but_other_value = $(this).val(), // or $(".btn-Other").val();
        btn_email_value = $(".btn-Email").val();

    $("form").submit();
  });

});
```

Comment: I think the `$` is because he's using `PHP` you don't need `jQuery` to do a simple form submit.

Comment: one final question. how would i retrieve the value of the button in my function,if the set button is clicked i would need to retrieve the value 'set' in my function. Would it be through php's get variable or something?

Comment: Added code for getting the value of the buttons. @web_bod that was only because of the `jquery-ajax` tag.

Answer (score 0):

change your HTML

```
<form id="test" name="test">
...
<button onclick="email_user();">Email</button>
<button onclick="setuser();"><? echo $set_value; ?></button>
</form>
```

your functions should submit the form for you:

```
document.getElementById("test").submit();
```

Comment: upon submission will my page contain the same post data in the url? thats what I need ..

Comment: the best way to learn is to try it out and see what happens, but yes - the form hasn't changed substantially - you're only updating the form tag, replacing the buttons and putting a line of script in your two functions - otherwise keep everything else the same.